# What kind of people are considered as foolish therefore not qualify to give money as charity?

Tags: tafseer, surat-an-nisa

I saw a verse in Quran saying not to give your property to the foolish but rather cloth and feed them.

So what type of beggars or people are deemed as foolish, as referred to in this verse?

> An-Nisa Verse No: 5
>
> وَلاَ تُؤْتُواْ السُّفَهَاء أَمْوَالَكُمُ الَّتِي جَعَلَ اللّهُ لَكُمْ قِيَاماً وَارْزُقُوهُمْ فِيهَا وَاكْسُوهُمْ وَقُولُواْ لَهُمْ قَوْلاً مَّعْرُوفًا
>
> And give not unto the foolish your property which Allah has made a means of support for you, but feed and clothe them therewith, and speak to them words of kindness and justice.

Comment: have look at the exegeses: http://quranx.com/Tafsirs/4.5

Comment: @MAKZ i am still not clear that if its ok for us to give unknown stranger who is a beggar while i dont know if they r just going to use money to buy drink as its bee found to be popular practice by the beggars in this country

Comment: well, that's a different story. the verse yu statd in the question says: `O guardians, do not give to the foolish, the squanderers from among men, women and children, your property, that is, the property that is theirs but held by you` . and that's clear. as to your new question, ie, `if its ok for us to give unknown stranger who is a beggar !(?)` , i would say: `whatever good you give to the beggars is an act of charity, but be advised, only give them what you think will be enough`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the context of the verses you mention refer to orphans that you have decided to take care of and have merged their property with yours. The verses tells us that we should test them if they are able to handle their property wisely and only to give them when they are mature enough to do so. Till then, you should take care of their needs.

So it does not refer to beggars.

Comment: I don't think so, the verse is about our property, not theirs at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to describe such people. Its like schizophrenia. When you read the symptoms, you may easily think that most of the people are schizophrenics. But when you see a real schizophrenic person, you will easily see the difference.

There are some people who are slow minded. They don't need special care to live (they can eat, dress etc by themselves), but they don't think properly, can easily be cheated by someone. They can't be made responsible for important things such as being a commander or being a boss of a company. They usually don't give any importance to earthly things, so when someone say them to give up their property or money, or to lend for a certain time, they don't think that this man may be cheating them and won't give back the money ever.

They are like mentally ill, but in a half degree. There are people who don't give any importance to earthly things with aware, but these are not aware. They are like having a child's mind.

Therefore, we shouldn't give them a full responsibility over property until they begin to think properly. This would be escaping from responsibility, and throwing a child into middle of the wolves. We can foresee that they will be cheated by someone soon, thus lose their property and will become poor and needy. Rather than giving them some money and let them take care of responsibility of that money, we should feed them and clothe them.

Also this verse may include some people which are not old/mature enough to take the responsibility of property such as teenagers or children.

Answer (score -1):

**I assume we can call some kinds of people as foolish ...**

> people who commit sin, addicts, and so forth.

**But totally, there are several main factors that people ought to observe when giving their alms (Sadaqah) to some specific group of poor people, such as:**

> Initially it would be better to give the alms to the people who are
>   from your closer familty, like parents, family, relatives
>
> Or Yatim (orphan), helpless and so forth.

**There is a significant issue that can help you that you should give alms to.**

> Give your alms to a poor people who won't consume the alms in the ways
>   of sins.

(Therefore, by paying attention to the matter above, you can recognize...)

Note: I suggest you to read the source below as a helpful site. (Regarding alms)

---

**Source(s):**

http://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa5126 (in Arabic)

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa5126 (in Farsi)

http://islamquest.net/ur/archive/question/fa5126 (in Urdu)

Comment: eh.... I guess you translated the reference? :)

Comment: Dear Adam, I did it solely to some extent. (of course not as a detailed and perfect). but hopefully it be helpful for you somewhat.